# Django admin on different domain

Tags: django, dns

How can I make the Django backend (and some views) accessible in a different domain?
Is it done via the Sites Framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a copy of `settings.py` and run the admin server with that settings file. Also, create a copy of `urls.py` (let's call it `admin_urls.py`). Then, in the copied settings file change this line:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'admin_urls.py'
```

To prevent access to admin on the main site, remove admin app from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and all references to admin views in `urls.py`.